# Error while using react native vector icons

Tags: react-native, icons, react-native-vector-icons

Not able to load icons pls help

**Render Error**

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
components) or a class/function (for composite
components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to
export your component from the file it's defined in, or
you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of HeaderConfig

**CODE**

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";

import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { View,Text } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons, MaterialIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
```